# How to email dropbox app file paths as clickable hyperlinks?

Tags: vba, windows, outlook, outlook-addin, dropbox

The company uses dropbox instead of local servers. We often send files to colleagues, but each user has a unique path to the file stored in the dropbox desktop app (e.g. C:\Users\username\Dropbox...).

I was thinking about writing a batch script to copy a file path and strip the beginning of the path.  I would then need another script to add the user specific prefix to the file path, and then open the folder/file in file explorer.

I believe I found a way to add a batch file into the menu that pops up when you right click a file/folder by editing the registry.  I was thinking it would be possible to write an Outlook add-in for the receiving user to prepend their drive/username etc. to the file path and then open the file/file explorer if a path to a folder is sent.

I was hoping to get some input on this approach, or to know if there is an easier way to handle this.  I haven't started any of the code yet.

Answer (score 1):

```
Why don't you just start using the Dropbox add-in for Outlook?
```

Dropbox has created an add-in that integrates with Microsoft Outlook. By connecting the Dropbox add-in to your Outlook account, you can:

- Replace email attachments with a shared link to any file, big or small
- Save email attachments that you receive directly to your Dropbox account
- Ensure those with access to a file see updates to it (since shared links always point to the latest version of a file, whereas attachments are just a static copy)
- Enabling the integration adds a Dropbox icon to the Outlook compose window. When you click this icon a pop-up window appears, allowing you to select from the contents of your Dropbox. A shared link to any selected file or folder will appear in the body of the email.

While this link looks like an attachment, it's, in fact, a shared link. This means no slow-down in sending emails, and no space limitations in your inbox.

Anyway, if you still want to develop an add-in for extracting an attachment's file path you need to start with [Walkthrough: Create your first VSTO Add-in for Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-creating-your-first-vsto-add-in-for-outlook?view=vs-2019).

The [NewMailEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.application.newmailex) event of the Application class which is fired once for every received item that is processed by Microsoft Outlook. The item can be one of several different item types, for example, `MailItem`, `MeetingItem` and etc. The `EntryIDsCollection` string contains the Entry ID that corresponds to that item.

The `NewMailEx` event fires when a new message arrives in the Inbox and before client rule processing occurs. You can use the Entry ID returned in the `EntryIDCollection` array to call the [NameSpace.GetItemFromID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getitemfromid) method and process the item. Use this method with caution to minimize the impact on Outlook performance.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion.  I had searched for this before, but it turns out the dropbox add-in will not work for POP/IMAP.  Unfortunately our email is served through G-Suite so this would exclude us from using the dropbox add-in.  Thank you for your other references, I'll keep chugging along trying to find a solution.